# date conversion failed on PROD, working fine in DEV

Tags: sql-server

I have a report that stopped working in production, it worked fine until a few weeks ago.  It is working fine in dev with identical code.  Both environments SQL Server 2012.

```
select SUM(oi.quantity_shipped) as [Quantity Shipped],
    oi.itemDescription as [Item Description],
    oi.itemLanguage
from order_items as oi
inner join orderX as x on oi.ID = x.id
where convert(date, x.shipDate) between '1/1/2016' and '1/1/2017'
group by oi.itemDescription,
    oi.itemLanguage
order by [Item Description]
```

The prod code returns error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

note that the x.shipDate can be a null.  Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: The format in my database for shipDate is varchar and when it contains a value it is formatted like: 2017-01-25

Comment: You have a bad value in the x.shipdate field. If you can, change that column's data type to datetime

Comment: You also should use the ANSI standard date format for strings. YYYY-MM-DD. That is the only string format that will always work regardless of dateformat.

Comment: @SeanLange You mean `'YYYYMMDD'` [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) "even if you try to use the seemingly unambiguous YYYY-MM-DD, this can break under certain scenarios -- such as when the user's language settings are set to French:"

Comment: thanks for the tips.  The shipDate is coming in from a fulfillment house so always should be same value.  I will verify however,,,

Comment: Found it - ! data error, my external system fed in 0000-00-00 !

Comment: @SqlZim yes...thanks for the correction.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry, I know you knew that. I'm sure I've seen you post about it in answers and comments before. I didn't mean to imply it was anything other than a typo.

Comment: @SqlZim - No need to apologize at all. Yes it was a typo but needed to be corrected. I would much rather have the correct information posted than personally be right. I appreciate your clarification as will others who stumble in here in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you found the bad data causing your error, here are some other things to keep in mind:

I think you might misunderstand `between`; unless you explicitly want to include all of January 1st, 2017. Also, use the `'YYYYMMDD'` string format for dates.

> Applications that use other APIs, or Transact-SQL scripts, stored procedures, and triggers, should use the unseparated numeric strings. For example, yyyymmdd as 19980924. - [Write International Transact-SQL Statements - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
select SUM(oi.quantity_shipped) as [Quantity Shipped],
    oi.itemDescription as [Item Description],
    oi.itemLanguage
from order_items as oi
inner join orderX as x on oi.ID = x.id
where convert(date, x.shipDate,120) >= '20160101' 
  and convert(date, x.shipDate,120) <  '20170101' 
group by oi.itemDescription,
    oi.itemLanguage
order by [Item Description]
```

Reference:

- [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some bad data in date field, you can leave those conversion error using try_convert as below:

```
select SUM(oi.quantity_shipped) as [Quantity Shipped],
    oi.itemDescription as [Item Description],
    oi.itemLanguage
from order_items as oi
inner join orderX as x on oi.ID = x.id
where try_convert(date, x.shipDate) between '1/1/2016' and '1/1/2017'
group by oi.itemDescription,
    oi.itemLanguage
order by [Item Description]
```

Comment: Please note that `try_convert` is 2012 +

Comment: Yes not supported, Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score -1):

Found it - ! data error, my external system fed in 0000-00-00 for shipDate!
Thanks to all for the tips and advice.